# How to change the gridview font size in android

Tags: android, gridview, fonts, size

How to change the Gridview font size in android. I bound some values in android Gridview, but some value are hide. How to change the Gridview font size. Please tell me. Example:

Loan Amount    10    10000000    10000, this is my gridview values, but i got

Loan Am        10    100000      10000,

like this only i got. Instead 10000000 value i got 100000 this amount shown and another zero half only shown. Please tell the solution.

This is my full layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:minWidth="10dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" >

</GridView>
```

My MainActivity:

```
URL jsonGRID = new URL("http://192.169.11.172/MobileService/Service1.svc/ApprovalDetails/"+spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString()+"/"+spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"/"+val+"");
            URLConnection jcGRID = jsonGRID.openConnection();
            BufferedReader readerGRID = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jcGRID.getInputStream()));
            String lineGRID = readerGRID.readLine();
            JSONObject jsonResponseGRID = new JSONObject(lineGRID);
            String Result1GRID =jsonResponseGRID.getString("ApprovalDetailsByPrpslNOResult");
            JSONObject jsonResponse1GRID = new JSONObject(Result1GRID);
            String Result2GRID = jsonResponse1GRID.getString("UtilTable");
            String RemoveNullGRID=Result2GRID.replace(",null","");
            String RemoveLoanAMt=RemoveNullGRID.replace("LoanAmount","LnAmt");
           StringTokenizer tokGRID = new StringTokenizer(RemoveLoanAMt, "[[,\\]");
           String fldvalsGRID[]=new String[tokGRID.countTokens()]; 
           int J=0;
           while(tokGRID.hasMoreTokens())
              {
               fldvalsGRID[J]=tokGRID.nextToken().replace("\"", "");
                  J++;
              }

           grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
           View v = null;
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fldvalsGRID);

            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What you have in GridView, I mean you sub layout.

Comment: I posted my layout there.

Comment: Have you any sub-layout in GridView?

Comment: Post the entire layout and the adapter code.

Comment: no, i don't have any sub-layout...

Comment: You need to use custom adapter to customize your GridView items. Search for tutorial on google.

Comment: two days i searched on google. I don't find any solution. If u can just post the link or coding.

Comment: [http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/) this is for starting. Once you understand the concept you'll know the rest.

Comment: when i click the Gridview then only the gridview items changed the font size, but i need when the Gridview load iteself it will show the change the font size.